# How do I parse a string representing a multidimensional array into an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

Given a string of the format

```
"(1,(2,3,4),(5,6,(7,8,9,a,(b,c,d))))"
```

What is the easiest way of converting this into a JavaScript array?

```
[1, [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, [7, 8, 9, 'a', ['b', 'c', 'd']]]]
```

The use of both integers and unqutoed strings prevents me from using inbuilt parsing, and the multidimensionality prevents me from using simple splits, or similar.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all strings will be unquoted, and no reserved characters (commas, brackets & quotes) will exist in the strings?

Comment: @MTCoster Yep, all of those characters within values are translated into numeric forms, so any comma, bracket, etc. will explicitly be used to define the array shape.

Comment: They’re all numeric forms? Are they just hex characters or is the base variable?

Comment: @MTCoster Sorry, every character is not translated to a numerical form, namely only instances of `(`, `)` and `,` are made into the form `&40;`, `&41;` and `&44;`.  I do have access to the serialiser however, so I can add other characters to be reserved, e.g. `"`.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use a regular expression to turn the parentheses into square brackets, surround the strings with quotes, and then `JSON.parse` it:

```js
const input = "(1,(2,3,4),(5,6,(7,8,9,a,(b,c,d))))";
const json = input
  .replace(/\(/g, '[')
  .replace(/\)/g, ']')
  .replace(/[a-z]+/g, '"$&"');
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach which uses a `replaceAll` function to replace the brackets from `(` -> `[` and `)` -> `]`, and makes sure all letters have quotes around them with regex:

```js
const string = "(1,(2,3,4),(5,6,(7,8,9,a,(b,c,d))))";

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
  var target = this;
  return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};

const replaced = string.replaceAll("(", "[").replaceAll(")", "]").replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/g, '"$&"');

console.log(JSON.parse(replaced));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a oneliner you can do this

```
const str = "(1,(2,3,4),(5,6,(7,8,9,a,(b,c,d))))";
const array = JSON.parse(input.replace(/\(|\)/g, (match) => match === ")" ? "]" : "[").replace(/[a-zA-Z-_]/g, '"$&"'));

console.log(array)
```